# TypeError: Cannot read property 'useGETForQueries' of undefined - GraphQL Hooks

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm using graphQL hooks for my project, I'm running into an issue with testing, it renders this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'useGETForQueries' of undefined`

It fails in this line of code that belongs to a search component:

`const [searchManual, { loading: searchLoading, data, error }] = useManualQuery(SEARCH_QUERY);`

By default `useGETForQuereies` is `false`, but not sure why this error comes up when running the test.  The project runs ok, it's just the test case.  I have explicitly added the boolean for that variable in the `GraphQlClient`

graphql interceptor JS file

```
const gqlAxios = axios.create()
gqlAxios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 403 )
        window.location.href = config.api.LOGIN_URL;
    
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log("responseError", error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
)
gqlAxios.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    config = {
      ...config,
      headers: {
          ...config.headers,
          'session': getCookieValue()
      }
    }
    return config;
  }
)


const fixed = config.api.APP_GQL_HOST;
const url = fixed + 'graphql';

export const client = new GraphQLClient({ url, fetch: buildAxiosFetch(gqlAxios), useGETForQueries: false });
```

the `client` constant will be exported to `index.js` and used as a value in the `ClientContext.Provider`.

```
const Wrapped = (
  <ClientContext.Provider value={client}>
    <App />
  </ClientContext.Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  Wrapped, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Could this be an error from jsdom, this is the actual console error from running a test:

```
console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'useGETForQueries' of undefined]
```

If so, how can this be resolved? I'm just trying to solve pass a simple test case:

```
it('Expect component in the document', () => {

        const { getByTestId } = render(<Search />);
        const component = getByTestId("test");
        expect(component).toBeInTheDocument();

    });
```

Is there an extra configuration I need to be adding? I would like to use `msw` , mock service worker, but I'm stuck with this error and can not move forward.  Has anyone experience this error with `graphql hooks`? Also what's your experience with this library? The pro is that is lightweight but it seems to be not user friendly when it comes to testing. Any comparison with Apollo.  I appreciate your insights with this issue.

Comment: @xadm I'm already using `GraphQLClient`, see `export const client = new GraphQLClient({ url, fetch: buildAxiosFetch(gqlAxios), useGETForQueries: false });`

Comment: I see it now, opened issue too ;)